# Where is Windows explorer

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

Wasn't there a thing called "explorer" on the desktop, for getting around on the computer?

Not Internet explorer, but the local tool. Just on the local machine.

Somehow it's gone...

Where is in in Windows Visat?

Comment: "windows explorer" still exists, start typing it in the search box.

Comment: thanks Tyson, but it did not perform.  I've got Vista, if that's a facotr

Comment: press windows key + w

Answer (score 2):

Windows Explorer is 'the desktop' & everything displayed on it, icons, open windows showing folders etc. The only time it wouldn't be active would be if you had manually quit it or it had crashed.

Tap the Windows Key or click Start & start typing windows explorer - it will be the first item in the list. Opening it will just show you a new folder window, Libraries by default on Windows 7 [I'm not sure which in Vista].
If it isn't, then it may be a symptom of a more serious issue... though if Explorer wasn't running you'd have difficulty doing anything on the computer at all [as you'd have no icons, no task bar] unless you know how to start tasks from the Task Manager.

Comment: OK, alright, thanks guys... I got it. Close the query. RIP, etc

Comment: Thank tetsujin.   It did not perform as you prompted, but I did get the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Explorer is located at C:\Windows\explorer.exe

Comment: @buckyhaw you're welcome :)